# Textboxes of same id in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have Textboxes in UI as inside a grid . I mean to say many textboxes with the Same IDs
 `@Html.TextBox("Buyer Charge")`
in Source code it appaers as :
`<input id="Buyer_Charge" name="Buyer Charge"  type="text" value="1.0000" />`

Here are my queries

1. I'm firing an event on blur of textbox of id - "Buyer_Charge". Its firing only for the first row text box. Its not hapening for next rows of textboxes in that grid
2. I want to format the Text value to Currency value in("$###,###,###,##0.00")

Pls let me know the soultions for my queries

Comment: I have same  ids for the textboxes throughout the page.But still then its not firing the event

Comment: change id to class, coz id is unique..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `id`'s should be unique in a page. That's the reason why it only fires on the first one as what you have said.

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/V28pC/1/)

But! If you can't help it, here's a little trick.

```
$('[id=Buyer_Charge]').css('border', '1px solid red');
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/V28pC/)

and to format your `<input>`, try [masked plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#demo).

Answer (score 0):

my understanding is that IDs are always supposed to be unique and that in the event there are multiples of the same ID, the code will only affect the first found, which is what you're saying.

That said, something like

```
$(#Buyer_Charge).each(function(){ change format });
```

may be what you're looking for.  Consider turning the IDs into classes in your html, too.

A class should define elements that act the same way where an ID should refer to a specific element.

Answer (score 0):

U should change ID to class, coz id is unique.

and you can loop it with .each() method and set .focus() method to change border of text input
About formatting value to currency, you can use .each() method again and use your code to set_currency.

```
$('.Buyer_Charge).each(function(){ set_currency });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jowan/dMpFa/2/) In demo I just create event blur on your text input